# Upload file Cordova node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova

I'm trying to upload a file from a cordova app to a node server. I am getting this exception in the server side

```
Cannot read property 'file' of undefined
```

i'm newbie in javascript and i need help thanks 
this is the client code

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture(
            uploadPhoto,
            function(message) { alert('get picture failed'); },
            {
                quality         : 50,
                destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType      : navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
            }
        );
    }

    function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

        var params = {};
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";

        options.params = params;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://10.20.160.38:3000/images"), win, fail, options);
    }

    function win(r) {
        console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        console.log("Response = " + r.response);
        console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
        console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
        console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
    }

    </script>
```

and this is the server code

```
(function () {

    var serverURL = "http://192.168.1.4:3000", // IMPORTANT: This URL needs to be accessible from your phone for testing.
        $scroller = $('.scroller'),

        // Get List of images from server
        getFeed = function () {
            $scroller.empty();
            $.ajax({url: serverURL + "/images", dataType: "json", type: "GET"}).done(function (data) {
                var l = data.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    $scroller.append('<img src="' + serverURL + '/' + data[i].fileName + '"/>');
                }
            });
        },

        // Upload image to server
        upload = function (imageURI) {
            var ft = new FileTransfer(),
                options = new FileUploadOptions();

            options.fileKey = "file";
            options.fileName = 'filename.jpg'; // We will use the name auto-generated by Node at the server side.
            options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
            options.chunkedMode = false;
            options.params = { // Whatever you populate options.params with, will be available in req.body at the server-side.
                "description": "Uploaded from my phone"
            };

            ft.upload(imageURI, serverURL + "/images",
                function (e) {
                    getFeed();
                },
                function (e) {
                    alert("Upload failed");
                }, options);
        },

        // Take a picture using the camera or select one from the library
        takePicture = function (e) {
            var options = {
                quality: 45,
                targetWidth: 1000,
                targetHeight: 1000,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
            };

            navigator.camera.getPicture(
                function (imageURI) {
                    alert(imageURI);
                    upload(imageURI);
                },
                function (message) {
                    // We typically get here because the use canceled the photo operation. Fail silently.
                }, options);

            return false;

        };

    $('.camera-btn').on('click', takePicture);

    getFeed();

}());
```

Comment: If the error is occurring on the server side, then you should post the server-side code (where you are handling the file upload request) where the error is coming from.

Comment: it's ok the problem is that i'm using express 4.x and bodyparser was replaced by busboy thanks